# retrieve linkedin profile url from php api

Tags: php, api, curl, xml-parsing, linkedin-api

I am using the [Simple LinkedIn PHP Library](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2355) to create a searching feature for an application. The user can search through LinkedIn and retrieve matched users information. As of right now the feature is working properly, but how can I parse the XML returned by the API and get the user's ID to create a link to their profile?

This is a sample of the array returned by the API call:

```
{
  "numResults": 17325,
  "people": {
    "_count": 10,
    "_start": 0,
    "_total": 110,
    "values": [
      {
        "firstName": "Leon",
        "headline": "Digital Marketing | Mobile Marketing | Video Marketing | SEO/SEM | Digital Media Sales Trainer",
        "id": "EFMHqoTad3",
        "lastName": "E. Spencer",
        "pictureUrl": "http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_jOgiHrinvW_afCa6PRDyHPXZBdvfi3a6xyWyHPXke7T0p5JQl4SfQ1KEMXzr86fopjxjFqnEf1I-"
      },
```

If I understand correctly, a users profile url looks like `http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=156996610` so I should just be able to extract the ID from the API call and append to the `view?id=` query right? Can I do this with the SimpleXML PHP Library?

Comment: Why the random down vote 2 years later?

Answer (score 0):

By XML I believe you mean JSON.

One way in php is by using the `json_decode()` function.

`$url = file_get_contents("http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=156996610");`

`$json =json_decode($url,true);`

the second value "true" means it will be returned as an associative array.

Then you can access whatever you want from that response.

I.E a user ID..

`$userID = $json['people']['values']['id'];`

I suggest reading the  [json_decode() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to understand how this works.